# How to pass table row to hidden form with all input elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have working on my project where I created table with multiple rows. Now I want to submit elements from table row where user enter their information but not entire from. So I was wondering what is the best way to pass all the element from that table row to hidden from that way I can submit just information from that specific row. Here is my code:

```
<form name='slotsPtc' id='slotsPtc' method='POST'>
   <table>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>Slot_Label</td>
          <td><span>
              <input type='text' name='EMAIL' value='' class="email"/>
              <input type='button' name='slot' value='Save' onClick='saveSlot(this)'></span>
              <input type='hidden' value='userID'/>
              <input type='hidden' value='dateSignUp'/>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

function saveSlot(btn){
   //Here I want to submit my form with information entered in table row.
}
```

Should I pass information to my function after onClick event and then create dynamically form and pass all information? Or there is some better way to do this?

Comment: you can use Ajax to send your information as a json to the server without creating a new form

Comment: A regular submit will submit all inputs inside your `<form>` but you can do a custom submit with `jQuery` with a custom `data` member.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is:

```js
function saveSlot(btn){
  var frm = document.getElementById('slotsPtc');
  // disable the button until the form is successfully submitted or on failure
  // this to avoid to submit while submitting the same data
  btn.disabled = true;
  $.ajax({
    url: frm.action,
    type: frm.method,
    data: $(btn).parent('tr').find(':input').serialize(),
    success: function(result) {
      // enable again the button
      btn.disabled = false;
      // form submitted with success
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      // enable again the button in any case
      btn.disabled = false;
      // form submitted with failure
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form name='slotsPtc' id='slotsPtc' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Slot_Label</td>
            <td><span>
              <input type='text' name='EMAIL' value='' class="email"/>
              <input type='button' name='slot' value='Save' onClick='saveSlot(this)'></span>
                <input type='hidden' value='userID'/>
                <input type='hidden' value='dateSignUp'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Slot_Label1</td>
            <td><span>
              <input type='text' name='EMAIL1' value='' class="email"/>
              <input type='button' name='slot1' value='Save' onClick='saveSlot(this)'></span>
                <input type='hidden' value='userID1'/>
                <input type='hidden' value='dateSignUp1'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this code and for some reason my form is empty after I submit the form. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to do something like this, then POST your form data found via the selector:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('td input'));
});
```

Example (check your console for the object from the selector):

https://jsfiddle.net/yLk07esz/

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using this:

```
data: $(btn).parent('tr').find(':input').serialize()
```

I had to use this:

```
data:$j(btn).closest('td').find(':input').serialize()
```

For some reason when I used first line of code my form was empty after I submitted. Then I switched and used closest('td').find(':input') and that gave me correct input fields with valid values.